# "Recommended" Sign In user flow available?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

according to this documentation: [User flow versions in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-versions) there is no sign-in-only user flow recommended for production.
That doesn't make sense to me, what is the recommended procedure in case of the SIGN-IN-ONLY scenario (users are created by the application through Graph API)?

thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended section is for the major scenarios. The scenario where only sign in is desired - is less used. So recommended section has Signup or Sign in user flow.

You can use Signin only user flow form "All section" for your scenarios.